# Create a dataframe based on an old one

Tags: python-2.7

I have a dataframe as :

```
   A   B   C   D
   0   s   3   a
   4   s   2   a
   5   s   2   a
   6   s   1   a
   7   s   2   b
   7   s   3   b
   6   s   0   b
```

How can I create a new dataframe as the following?

```
   A   B   C   D
   0   4   8   4-a
   7   3   5   3-b
```

The new dataframe summarize the old one by grouped the elements of column "D", So "A" is the index, "B" is count of elements, "C" is sum of element where "D" has the same value.

Comment: what is your code so far?

Comment: I am looking how can I code it, I have only the data frame df = pd.read_csv("/data/mydata.txt", header = None)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, assuming that your data is stored in `df`,  it's a multistep process which could be done like this

```
import pandas as pd

data = {'A': {0: 0, 1: 4, 2: 5, 3: 6, 4: 7, 5: 7, 6: 6},
        'B': {0: 's', 1: 's', 2: 's', 3: 's', 4: 's', 5: 's', 6: 's'},
        'C': {0: 3, 1: 2, 2: 2, 3: 1, 4: 2, 5: 3, 6: 0},
        'D': {0: 'a', 1: 'a', 2: 'a', 3: 'a', 4: 'b', 5: 'b', 6: 'b'}}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)

# Handling column A (first index per value in D)
output_df = df.drop_duplicates(subset='D', keep='first')

# Itering through rows
for index, row in output_df.iterrows():

    #Calcultating the counts in B
    output_df.loc[index, 'B'] = df[df.D == row.D].B.count()

    #Calcultating the sum in C
    output_df.loc[index, 'C'] = df[df.D == row.D].C.sum()

#Finally changing values in D by concatenating values in B and D
output_df.loc[:, 'D'] = output_df.B.map(str) + "-" +  output_df.D
```

Output :

> ```
>    A   B   C   D
>    0   4   8   4-a
>    7   3   5   3-b
> ```

Comment: When I run the code I got :
.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/core/indexing.py:543: SettingWithCopyWarning:
A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame.
Try using .loc[row_indexer,col_indexer] = value instead
See the caveats in the documentation: http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#indexing-view-versus-copy
  self.obj[item] = s

Comment: The results are in the `output_df` dataframe. You just have to print it `print(output_df)`

Comment: .local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/core/generic.py:5096: SettingWithCopyWarning:
A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame.
Try using .loc[row_indexer,col_indexer] = value instead See the caveats in the documentation: http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#indexing-view-versus-copy
self[name] = value

Comment: Now I can see a results of output_df but it seems I have 2 columns, Index "A" and "D"
       A      D
       0     7-a

Comment: Every dataframe has an index. Eventually if you don't want to see the index of `output_df` you could do : `print (output_df.to_string(index=False))`.

Comment: Yes it works now, thank you :). But the new dataframe has no index

Comment: Hello Sebastien D, I see that it works to set up data as dataframe but I couldn t use the output_df as a normal dataframe, like if I want to select a column from and even I can t run output_df.info(). can you help to understand how can I use this output_df?

Comment: `output_df` actually is a regular `dataframe` you should be able to do any operations on it (as I can))

Comment: No I couldn't use it as a regular df, so I extract which column as a list then I set up a new df which is working fine now